# Необходима помощью в описании отражения шаров друг от друга на Javascript!

Tags: canvas, javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, у меня есть следующая задача: Необходимо создать анимацию (в html файле) движения n-шаров в квадрате, так чтобы они отражались по законам физики от стенок и друг от друга. С написанием кода программы для квадрата, шаров, их движения и отражения от стенок проблем не возникло, а вот с описанием отражением друг от друга есть трудности. Хотелось бы узнать как это возможно сделать!! Вот мой код в JS, строго не судите я как бы совсем новичок:
http://jsfiddle.net/JsJx7/1/

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Как я понимаю, отталкиваясь - шарики отлетают неправильно ? )))
Ну... если так, то JS тут не при чем. Нужно геометрию и физику вспомнить. ПОпробую что-нить придумать )

Comment: Ага! Физика тут абсолютно упругого удара массы равны и скорости! Просто остается учесть направление шаров кто с какой стороны прилетел. Это я пытался сделать но не получилось((

Comment: если совсем по простому то вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JsJx7/2/